# Web Audio FFT of an Oscillator?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, fft, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the Web Audio's FFT on the Oscillator.

relevant code:

```
var context = new window.webkitAudioContext

var osc = context.createOscillator()
var an = context.createAnalyser()
osc.connect(an)
an.connect(context.destination)

osc.start(0)
osc.stop(context.currentTime + 2) //play sine wave for 2 seconds

var freqDomain = new Int8Array(an.frequencyBinCount)
an.getByteFrequencyData(freqDomain)
console.dir(freqDomain) //all 0's
```

also, calling `an.getTimeDomainData` doesn't return anything either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in the above code is, you immediately attempt to get the Byte Frequency Data -- but there's no data yet as the audio hasn't started. The `getByteFrequencyData` needs to be called whenever you want to copy the data from the AnalyserNode into the `freqDomain` array.

You can up a [ScriptProcessorNode](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#ScriptProcessorNode-section), or use a simple `setInterval` to call the analysis, like

```
var freqDomain = new Int8Array(an.frequencyBinCount);

function proc () {
  an.getByteFrequencyData(freqDomain);
  console.log(freqDomain[0]); // Just output one element so we don't destroy the console
}
setInterval(proc, 22);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it without playing the sound and waiting the duration?

Comment: Then the analyser node would never receive any data; depending on the goal, the offlineAudioContext may do what you need

Comment: My goal is to leverage the FFT of the web audio API for analysis of non-audio data/signals. Is this even a good idea? Or should I be looking at one of the JavaScript DFT packages?

Comment: Probably would be easier/make more sense to just use a DSP library with FFT/DFT algorithms

Comment: Probably. I'm still curious though, I'd still think it's possible to do this real-time without actually playing the signal... right?

Comment: You could use a ScriptProcessorNode to create the audio buffer and push your data to the output buffer, wire the ScriptProcessorNode into an Analyser node, and don't direct it to the context.destination probably

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! But wait 22 ms was not sufficient, it worked until 40 ms.